# What is XMPP, and how can I use it within an iOS chat application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xmpp

I want to create a chat client application for iPhone. I've read that the XMPP framework is one of the best to use for this. However, I haven't found much material out there on this, only the XMPPFramework on Google Code and details about it on a wiki.

Can anyone explain what XMPP is and how we can use it within our chat application? Are there any tutorials or code snippets out there that demonstrate its use?

Comment: [Your Google-fu is weak, young padawan](http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/).    No code snippet is possible for XMPP *itself*, as XMPP is a highly complex XML-based protocol that you probably don't actually want to deal with at the XML level.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but can you please suggest how I can integrate with my iPhone , I want to create a Clint using XMPP .Can you please help me how to do so???

Comment: If any other way without XMPP that wil also be acceptable. So any one can provide me the way to create chat client for ios ???

Comment: @MiteshKhatri - Bad luck of me the given link is not working now :(

Comment: You could try to look into some open-source applications that implement xmpp themselves: https://monal.im/ https://chatsecure.org/ https://astrachat.com/ https://siskin.im/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

XMPP is an open protocol for messaging and presence that most IM clients support.

If you're building a chat app for iOS that needs to interact with other clients, use XMPP. Read up and understand the protocol first, then look at the XMPPFramework Objective-C lib and it should all make sense. It'll take some time to learn though.

If your chat app needs to only communicate with other installations of your app, then you have a few easier options:

You could open a persistent tcp connection with the server and use that to pass presence and message data back and forth. You could implement a simple server to do this in node.js, for example, in a relatively small amount of code.

An even easier option is to call a simple http based api when you want to report new messages or presence changes from the iphone and deliver updates via push messages. Push messages are good because when the app is closed you can still deliver the message and when the app is open you can intelligently update your app's interface.

It's all about your requirements.

Answer (score 4):

V. Have you implemented XMPP?
I know it's too late to answer, but as now a days I am working on XMPP iOS app, and now we are having comparatively much information available over XMPP, I feel to write here.

Here is one of the best tutorial available for integrating XMPP:

[1. Building a jabber client for iOS](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-setup--mobile-7190)
[2. XMPP Messanger for iOS - GitHub](https://github.com/processone/xmpp-messenger-ios)

It is very powerful and really instant protocol to use for IM (as we all know hoe WhatsApp is using it).

We can even integrate OMEMO Encryption for our IM App.

Comment: Yes I did! With the help of Signal app source code.

Comment: Can you suggest any example/tutorials which will give a detailed idea about how we may do this OMEMO integration. We have a XMPP client and am trying to add OMEMO, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I haven’t found any tutorial, just gone th’r Signal source code. But thinking to create Github repo with implementation, will update here...

Comment: @AngelFSyrus given XMPP GitHub repo can be used directly in `Swift` project, using bridging header for Obj-C files.

Comment: @D4ttatraya Thankyou for your reply. Can you please explain me what are the steps you follow for real chat app

Comment: @AngelFSyrus [This ReadMe](https://github.com/processone/xmpp-messenger-ios) explains step-by-step how to build a chat app in Swift

Comment: I tried this too but its seen years ago so showing so many errors:(

Answer (score 3):

The most known XMPP iOS framework is [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework).
It provides a core implementation of RFC-3920 (the XMPP standard). The framework is massively parallel and thread-safe. Performance is good thanks to GCD. It comes with multiple [popular extensions](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/XEPs) (XEP's).

You can find a very well written Swift tutorial to implement XMPPFramework in your application. Here is the [first part](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/blog/build-a-complete-ios-messaging-app-using-xmppframework-tutorial-part-1.html) and the [second part](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/blog/build-a-complete-ios-messaging-app-using-xmppframework-part-2.html)

Alternative can be:

- [DCXMPP](https://github.com/daltoniam/DCXMPP) but it hasn't been maintained since 2014.
- [Libstrophe](http://strophe.im/libstrophe/) which is a C library. You can find an iOS version [here](https://github.com/gameclosure/libstrophe-ios). Same it hasn't been maintained since 2013